# Inheritance Overriding

Tags: c++, oop, virtual

I have a question regarding early/late binding during inheritance overriding.

So I am going over basics OOP for C++, and read that if you don't declare a function on the base class virtual, you can't override it.  However I have the following code and it looks like my compiler is overriding it for me anyways.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Book{
public:
    string title;
    int number;

    Book(){
    }

    Book(string title){
        cout << "book " << title << " created" << endl;
    }

    void setNumber(int num){
        number = num + 7;
    }

    ~Book(){
        cout << "book " << title << " destroyed:";
    }
};

class Magazine: public Book {
public:

    void setNumber(int num){
    number = num;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Magazine mag;
    mag.setNumber(4);
    cout << mag.title << endl;
    cout << "the number you are looking for is: " << mag.number << endl;
}
```

the output on my compiler is 4, but based on what I've read c++ has early binding and if a function is not declared virtual in the base class it shouldn't be possible to override it so it should output num + 7 as stated on the base class. Did I simply get an incorrect resource?  Or would this possibly be a bug/anomaly in my compiler?

Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 5):

You can "override" non-virtual functions, yet the implementation will not be dynamically bound but statically. You'll realise the difference in conjunction with polymorphism:

```
Book* mag = new Magazine();
mag->setNumber(4);
cout << mag->title << endl;
cout << "the number you are looking for is: " << mag->number << endl;
```

This will invoke the `Book`-implementations, whereas when you had declared the member functions virtual, it would be dynamically bound to the Magazines implementation.

Comment: +1 but I think mentioning `override` and showing an example of the "fixed" code would help complete this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are not overriding your function. The thing you do is *redefining*

If you want to be sure that you overrided function put `override` keyword after your function declaration to see actually you overrided or not.

Example:

`void suspicious() override;` -(C++11 feature)

Also it’s good to know, if you redefine a function *“which function to use(type checking) ”* happens at compile time and if you declare your function virtual with same name it happens at run time via virtual table mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The `virtual` keyword really only comes into play when you're dealing with Polymorphism. And that only happens when you have pointers/references.

If you have instead done something like:

```
int main()
{
    Magazine mag;
    Book *b = &mag;
    b->setNumber(4);
    cout << b->title << endl;
    cout << "the number you are looking for is: " << b->number << endl;
}
```

You'll see that we end up calling `Book::setNumber()`, even though we're actually pointing to a `Magazine`!

If you declare `setNumber` as a `virtual` function and run the above code, you'll be using dynamic function binding. So instead of immediately going to call `Book::setNumber()` since we have a `Book` pointer, the program will dynamically check to see what `b` is actually pointing to. Since it's actually a `Magazine` object, we'll then call `Magazine::setNumber()`. This is the magic that is Polymorphism.

Comment: " And that only happens when you have pointers" - or references.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempt to explain, I recommend you try the following experiment:

```
Book &book = Mag;
book.setNumber(4);
cout << mag.number << endl;
```

And then repeat that with `Book::setNumber` declared `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if a function in a base class isn't declared as virtual, it won't be overridden in the derived class. What's happening in your code isn't actually overriding; it's function hiding. When you have a function in the derived class with the same name as in the base class, the base class's function is hidden in objects of the derived class. To ensure proper overriding, declare the function as virtual in the base class and use override in the derived class. That way, the function behaves as expected based on the object's actual type when you call it.